# Casting custom screen to Chromecast with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, chromecast

I want to cast a custom screen (widgets) to a chromecast. Not just a video. I know there are two packages (cast and dart_chromecast), but neither have been able to detect any devices.

Is there a way to achieve this or can I maybe do it natively?